# fastai.text NameError: name 'BaseTokenizer' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, fast-ai

I am a beginner of fastai and trying to build a model referring to [Using RoBERTa with fast.ai for NLP](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-roberta-with-fastai-for-nlp-7ed3fed21f6c).

I was trying to customize the tokenizer (as the code below):

```
from fastai.text import *
from fastai.metrics import *
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer

class FastAiRobertaTokenizer(BaseTokenizer):
    """Wrapper around RobertaTokenizer to be compatible with fastai"""
    def __init__(self, tokenizer: RobertaTokenizer, max_seq_len: int=128, **kwargs): 
        self._pretrained_tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_seq_len = max_seq_len 
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        return self 
    def tokenizer(self, t:str) -> List[str]: 
        """Adds Roberta bos and eos tokens and limits the maximum sequence length""" 
        return [config.start_tok] + self._pretrained_tokenizer.tokenize(t)[:self.max_seq_len - 2] + [config.end_tok]
```

But got an error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-41070aae72d1> in <module>
----> 1 class FastAiRobertaTokenizer(BaseTokenizer):
      2     """Wrapper around RobertaTokenizer to be compatible with fastai"""
      3     def __init__(self, tokenizer: RobertaTokenizer, max_seq_len: int=128, **kwargs):
      4         self._pretrained_tokenizer = tokenizer
      5         self.max_seq_len = max_seq_len

NameError: name 'BaseTokenizer' is not defined
```

- fastai version: 2.1.8
- torch version: 1.7.1
- transformers version: 3.4.0

Did anyone get the same issue before?

Comment: One issue may be that the linked article indicates that it was written for fastai version 1, yet you are using fast ai version 2. You may not be able to follow the tutorial with fastai version 2 without significant changes to the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried to install the v1 version of fastai, but it seemed there are a lot of problems, for one example, when I import fastai.text, it showed that I was missing some modules. Those modules are already been installed yet the version cannot support fastai.

Comment: You might have better luck with this tutorial using fast.ai v2: https://docs.fast.ai/tutorial.transformers . Huggingface has done a great job of keeping the api consistent across models, so once you're up and running with one model, it's not too hard to work with a different one.

Comment: I figured out the answer via that documentation, thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Oh, I finally figure out that I should change `from fastai.text import *` to `from fastai.text.all import *`. There is no error message `NameError: name 'BaseTokenizer' is not defined` left.