# NameError: name 'TokenizeProcessor' is not defined

Tags: python, bert-language-model, fast-ai

I am running a BERT model with fastai for text classification for the first time. I follow the instructions and source code provide [in this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/keitakurita/bert-with-fastai-example/comments), including the following import statements:

```
from fastai.text import * 
from fastai.callback.all import * # instead of from fastai.callbacks import *
from pytorch_pretrained_bert.modeling import BertConfig, BertForSequenceClassification
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer
```

However, I got an error from this line:

```
class BertTokenizeProcessor(TokenizeProcessor):
```

The error is

> " NameError: name 'TokenizeProcessor' is not defined"

I think the problem is related to the imported packages, especially fastai, as [fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0nEm.jpg) shows that TokenizeProcessor is not included in fastai. But I am not sure which and how to fix such an error.

Python version: 3.6.5,
fastai version: 2.3.1

Thank you,

Comment: Please show your full code as a [mcve]

Comment: It probably has something to do with your import statement. If you imported the library as `import lib` (where `lib` is the name of the library) you'd need to use it like so: `class BertTokenizeProcessor(lib.TokenizeProcessor): ...`.

Comment: Check this link first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376957/7456750

Comment: Thank @OneCricketeer for your reply. I just reimplement the mentioned tutorial as it is. However, I made a tiny change in importing statement  (from fastai.callbacks import *) to be (from fastai.callback.all import *).

Comment: Thank you, @RoyCohen for your comment. I  tried but it does not work, and I cannot find the “TokenizeProcessor” class in fastai package (V. 2.3.1). However, I found it in stanfordnlp package, but such package did not import by related tutorials.

Comment: You've still not made an [edit] to your post to show your full import statements like I asked

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses, I found that fastai is not running perfectly with macOS. Thus, all required classes weren't downloaded. Instead, I used google colab, which I deeply recommended, to run the tutorial.